# How to add an event listener to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working on a specific project, using touch screens and iframes.  I have a simple iframe in a test.html file as so:

```
  <iframe id="framey" src="http://www.w3schools.com/"></iframe>
```

I am trying to add an event listener which lets the spacebar refresh the whole page (test.html) and listens the entire time, even when navigating through the iframe site.

Here is my javascript:

```
 $("#framey").on("keyup",function(e)
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 32){
                 location.reload();
            }  
        })
```

At the moment, it only does it on the initial click, but not after that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe

Read about iframe from this link. The attribute "sandbox" might be helpful for this specific problem